# Flutter: IconButton selectedIcon not applying

Tags: flutter, dart, iconbutton

I want to create an effect of changing the icon to its fill version on press on an `IconButton`, and I am using the selectedIcon option to achieve it.

The problem is that the icon is not changing event though I think I have done the right setting.

Here is the code:

```
IconButton(
        isSelected: _homeSelected,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _homeSelected = true;
            _bookedSelected = false;
            _ticketsSelected = false;
            _settingsSelected = false;
          });
        },
        icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.house),
        selectedIcon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.house_fill),
        color: (_homeSelected ? _selectedIconColor : _iconColor),
        iconSize: (_homeSelected ? _selectedIconSize : _iconSize),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Statefulbuilder,when you setstate like this widget rebuild.and initialize its old values.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html

```
     StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
          return IconButton(
    isSelected: _homeSelected,
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        _homeSelected = true;
        _bookedSelected = false;
        _ticketsSelected = false;
        _settingsSelected = false;
      });
    },
    icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.house),
    selectedIcon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.house_fill),
    color: (_homeSelected ? _selectedIconColor : _iconColor),
    iconSize: (_homeSelected ? _selectedIconSize : _iconSize),
  ),});
```

Comment: when using statefulbuilder, the state is maitained and when I reclick on the button or on another button, it is not changing anymore

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to change onPressed
if you do this(_homeSelected = true) then value is always true so need to change with _homeSelected=!_homeSelected

```
onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        _homeSelected = !_homeSelected;
        _bookedSelected = false;
        _ticketsSelected = false;
        _settingsSelected = false;
      });
    },
```